# Combination SAML and SSL Offloader causes error

Tags: adfs, saml

Last night we tried to migrate a website to our new hosting provider. This new hosting provider uses a SSL offloader and this causes a problem with a website using SAML. After the migration when we tried to login using SAML we got the error below, in the error and web.config I have changed the name of the customer to customer. We think SAML expects a HTTPS response but it gets a HTTP response. Is there a way to influence this from the web.config. I have also added a piece of the web.config with the most of the customer configuration regarding SAML, we also tried it with the CookieHandler on False but same error. I hope you guys can help us out!

### Web.Config Configuration

```
<!-- SAML authService -->
<kentor.authServices
   entityId="customersaml"
   returnUrl="https://customer.domain.com"
   validateCertificates="false">
   <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="http://ahauth01.customer.nl/adfs/services/trust" signOnUrl="https://ahauth01.customer.nl/adfs/ls/" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpPost">
            <signingCertificate fileName="~/Config/customer.crt" />
        </add>
    </identityProviders>
</kentor.authServices>

<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="true"/>
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>

<system.identityModel>
    <identityConfiguration>
      <securityTokenHandlers>
        <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
          <audienceUris mode="Never" />
        </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
      </securityTokenHandlers>
    </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

---

ERROR

*Saml
Customersaml
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Policy.PolicyServer.Engine.AssertionConsumerServiceUrlDoesNotMatchPolicyException: MSIS3200: No AssertionConsumerService is configured on the relying party trust 'microsoft:identityserver:Customersaml' that is a prefix match of the AssertionConsumerService URL 'http://Customer.domain.com/AuthServices/Acs' specified by the request.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.EndpointResolver.LookupAssertionConsumerServiceByUrl(Collection`1 assertionConsumerServices, Uri requestedAssertionConsumerServiceUrl, String scopeIdentity)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.EndpointResolver.FindSamlResponseEndpointForAuthenticationRequest(Boolean artifactEnabled, AuthenticationRequest request, ScopeDescription scopeDescription)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.GetResponseEndpointFromRequest(SamlRequest request, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, ScopeDescription scope)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)*

Answer (score 0):

Check the relying party trust on AD FS and look at endpoints. Does it have an endpoint for the path 'http://Customer.domain.com/AuthServices/Acs' ?